# iOS CoreBluetooth suddenly in CBManagerStateResetting state

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

**Issue:**

Recently, I am frequently getting **CBManagerStateResetting** state in CBPeripheralManager. After getting CBManagerStateResetting state, **CBManagerStatePoweredOn** comes within 3~5 seconds. However, this not only effect the application but also peer device is getting disconnect status due to link loss error.

**Scenario:**

This issue occurs specially during continuous data transaction in BLE while parallelly using 3G Data from iPhone.

When CBManagerStateResetting occurs, peer device gets disconnected. It is so annoying now a days as it is occurring frequently.

**My question,**

- Why CBManagerStateResetting state comes while app is already connected to a BLE device?
- What steps can be taken from iOS Application side and peer device side to prevent this reset issue ?

Extra information:
CBPeripheralManagerStates are as follows:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CBPeripheralManagerState) {
CBPeripheralManagerStateUnknown = CBManagerStateUnknown,
**CBPeripheralManagerStateResetting = CBManagerStateResetting,**
CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported = CBManagerStateUnsupported,
CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized = CBManagerStateUnauthorized,
CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff = CBManagerStatePoweredOff,
CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn = CBManagerStatePoweredOn,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens due to an unstable Bluetooth stack when Apple first released iOS 10. In the subsequent update, the issue has been solved. In current releases "CBPeripheralManagerStateResetting" comes rarely.